# Why is the HttpServletRequest null in the MessageContext?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I am trying to get the IP Address of the client of my JAX-WS SOAP Web Service (an alternative solution is appreciated).

I am using the following code, which works on another project, however this project (integrating with Spring 3.2.4) is returning a null **HttpServletRequest** when I fetch it from the javax.xml.ws.**WebServiceContext** (the WebServiceContext is **not null**):

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;

private String getRemoteIpAddress()
{
   MessageContext context = this.wsContext.getMessageContext();
   HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
   String remoteIpAddress = httpRequest.getRemoteAddr();
```

For further clarity, this is this Web Service class looks like:

```
@WebService(name = "PService", targetNamespace = "http://server.ps/")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class PSystemServiceEndpoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport
```

Important to note, the application is running as a **standalone Java application** and includes a **Jetty Embeeded Server**.

Comment: Spring based components are generally singletons and as such injection is done once. So you will reuse the `WebServiceContext` from the start of your application and I highly doubt that this has a `HttpServletRequest` nor that it has the correct `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm looking for an alternative to get the Client's Remote IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Spring WS and when I need to get IP from remote client I use this function

```
private String getIpRequest(){
    String result = "none";

    TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();

    if(context != null){
        HttpServletConnection connection = (HttpServletConnection)context.getConnection();
        if(connection != null){
            HttpServletRequest request = connection.getHttpServletRequest();
            if(request != null){
                result = request.getRemoteAddr();
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

As you can see I don't use `WebServiceContext`, instead I use `WebServiceTemplate` so I am not sure if this code is right for you, but I hope it helps.

Comment: TransportContext is not in my classpath, I guess you're using Spring 2, not Spring 3.2; however the approach looks real nice as I can probably move my code to outside the service class using it.
On the other hand, I don't see the WebServiceTemplate you mentioned in your sample code.

Comment: That code is from a project using Spring`4.1.2.RELEASE` and Spring-WS `2.2.0.RELEASE`. You don't see WebServiceTemplate because it doesn't appear in that piece of code, I told you for your info.

Comment: OK however I didn't understand the bit about the WebServiceTemplate. Too bad your solution didn't help me yet. Thanks.